# How to compute a simple convolution

Tags: integration, convolution

$$
q(t)=\begin{cases}
0& t<0\\\\
1-t& 0<t<1\\\\
0& t>1
\end{cases}$$

How do I compute the $ h(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} q(t+\tau ) d \tau $

I know this suppose to be basic but I get very confused on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $t$. Then, $$q(t+\tau)=\begin{cases}0&t+\tau<0\\1-(t+\tau)&0<t+\tau<1\\0&t+\tau>1\end{cases}.$$

Therefore, $$\int_{-\infty }^\infty q(t+\tau)\,\mathrm d \tau=\int_{-t}^{1-t}1-(t+\tau)\,\mathrm d \tau=...$$

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: I edited my answer... @Tomer

Comment: And I assume that h(t) = the value of integral only when  -1<t< 1 , otherwise it is zero right ?

Comment: no, whenever $t\in \mathbb R$. Try to see what happen if $t=2$ for example ;-) $(h(t)\neq 0$...)